# How to repeat actions after key is hold for a certain amount of time?

Tags: c#, xna, keyboard, repeat

I am currently developing in XNA/C#.
When the user presses a key (`Keys.Right`), I need to move an object.
I want this to happen

1. when the user presses the key
2. after 1 second while the user is holding the key and then every .25 seconds.

I already implemented the first one:

```
_kbOld = _kbNew;
_kbNew = _kb.GetState();
if(_kbNew.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) &&
   _kbOld.IsKeyUp(Keys.Right))
{
    //Do something
}
```

How would I do the other actions?
I had the following ideas:

- A `Queue<KeyboardState>`, keeping track of the last `KeyboardState`s
- Saving the time the key was last pressed and when it was released (`GameTime`)

It should work like text input in Windows: When you hold a letter, it will repeat after a certain amount of time.

Which way should I use? Do you have other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend using windows hooks to get the actual keypresses, bypassing XNA's input maganement.

Comment: Because it will not only solve this problem, but also will capture symbols from any keyboard layout (different languages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply store the last push time, like you suggested:

```
if (IsPressed())
{
    // Key has just been pushed
    if (!WasPressed())
    {
        // Store the time
        pushTime = GetCurrentTime();

        // Execute the action once immediately
        // like a letter being printed when the button is pressed
        Action();
    }

    // Enough time has passed since the last push time
    if (HasPassedDelay())
    {
        Action();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to add some more conditions (Pressed this frame, Released this frame, Delay finished, Repetition), but it is basically what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I recall from doing something similar in javascript that

1. you create a timer, set its interval to 1 second, and then enable it on mousedown (keydown in your case). You will reset and disable it on keyup.
2. The second step is to tie your behaviour to the the Tick() event.
3. The third step is to check, inside your Tick() handler, if the state of Keys.Right is down and if not, to reset the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make your own Key and Keyboard class. In Keyboard you could make method updateInput() which would update state of every Key, where you could use advenced functions like this.
In Key class, you can use

> Saving the time the key was last pressed and when it was released
>   (GameTime)

@JuannStrauss
For sure not timer.